# Error installing zmq Node Module

Tags: node.js, zeromq

When installing the *zmq node module*, I get the following error. 
I have the latest stable version of node installed.

I am running a Mac on OS X 10.9.3

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zmq
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zmq
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> zmq@2.7.0 install /Users/mario/node_modules/zmq
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config libzmq --libs' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:340:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mario/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! zmq@2.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.7.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "zmq"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/mario/messaging
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mario/messaging/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Why do I get this error and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you already [installed ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software)? It must be installed first before the node.js module, which is just a binding to the already installed package.

Comment: Yes I installed zmq with Homebrew. `brew install zmq`

Comment: In the meantime I uninstalled _npm_ to reinstall it and am now having trouble installing it again! When I type `npm install -g` it return `npm: command not found`

Comment: If you uninstalled `npm`, then you can't use it to install itself again.

Comment: Then how do I install _npm_ again? I have just changed from a pc to a mac!

Comment: Ok I've got `npm` installed and running. I still encounter the same error when I call `npm install zmq`. Any help?

Comment: Looks like you need to install `pkg-config`: `/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found`  Try `brew install pkg-config`

Comment: @dylants Type your comment as an answer so I can vote it up ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to install `pkg-config`:

> /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found

Try `brew install pkg-config`